# Angular 4 HTTP request in guard

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use an HTTP request inside guard, but always getting errors.
when I remove the HTTP request and use an if condition, it's work.

**isAdmin.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router ,CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@injectable()

export class IsAdmin implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private auth:AuthService,
        private router:Router
    ){}


    canActivate(){
        //get user data
        this.auth.getUserData().subscribe((data)=>{
            if(data.isAdmin){
                return true;
            }else{
                this.auth.loggedIn();
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
        })
    }


}
```

**Photo from editor** 
[image]

[image]

Comment: TypeScript is case-sensitive. Injectable != injectable. Looking at a red squiggle isn't sufficient. You also need to **read** and **post** the error messages you get from the compiler. And you need to return something (an Observable<boolean> here) from the method. The router will subscribe to the observable you return. You must not subscribe yourself.

Comment: I return boolean but inside subscribe what should I have to in this case ?

Comment: the boolean is returned from the callback function passed to subscribe(). And this function is execute long after you've exited from the canActivate method: when the http response finally comes back. It's not returned from the canActivate() method. This is very important to understand. Again, you must not subscribe. You must return an Observable<boolean>.

Comment: can you give me a example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CanActivate must return a `Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean` as you can see in this [link](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).

```
interface CanActivate { 
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean
}
```

In your case, you should only return `this.auth.getUserData()`. But such function doesn't return an `Observable<boolean>`, instead, it returns `Observable<data>`. So you should map it to return a `Observable<boolean>`:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    //get user data
    return this.auth.getUserData().map((data)=>{
        if(data.isAdmin){
            return true;
        }else{
            this.auth.loggedIn();
            this.router.navigate(['/login']
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: great it's work , but in getUserData() I already map observable data why map again in guard not subscribe

Comment: Because the part of router code which will call `canActivate` can subscribe by itself. As well as you can return an observable, you can return a promise and the router will resolve by itself too.

Comment: How to catch an unauthorized 401 state?

Comment: @DanielEduardoDelgadoDiaz, you can use HTTP interceptor to catch it: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just to return an Observable(from which you can return `true` or `false`), as answered by @pedro-arantes but as of now in **2024** with latest **Angular/RxJS** you have to wrap the `map(...)` within `pipe()`

Refer to official docs for **[pipeable operators](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators)**

**Required Imports:**

```
import { Observable, map } from 'rxjs';
```

**canActivate() handler:**

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.auth.getUserData().pipe(
    map((data) => {
      if (data.isAdmin) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.auth.loggedIn();
        this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
        return false;
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Hope it helps, Thank you